# How to select multiple JPEGs in WORD 2011

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, selection

I'm trying to center a bunch of images in Word 2011, but they are interspersed in text. How do I select a group of them (normally Ctrl-Y with left click) such that I can select them all, then center them with the "center" format button (paragraph style)?

Comment: Are the pictures formatted as "in-line"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to create a style formatted the same way as you'd like your pictures to be.  Go to find/replace and select "Graphic" after clicking on the  "Special" button.  That will go in your "find" box.  For replace, click on the "Format" button and select "Style" and then find the style that you set up to format the pics.